# Visual Studio 2008 - Team Explorer - Keyboard shortcut

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, keyboard-shortcuts, team-explorer

Is there a keyboard shortcut to switch to Team Explorer?  For example, to switch to Solution Explorer it's <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.  But I cannot find one for Team Explorer.

Answer (score 7):

Yes it is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> , <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>

In the future if you need to find out what the keyboard shortcut is for a given item, the easiest way is to do the following

- Open Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard
- Type in the component name to "Show Commands Containing"
- Click on the appropriate command it it's shortcut, if present, will show in the shortcut menu.

After typing in "TeamExplorer" to 2010 Beta2, it show up only 4 commands, one of which is `View.TeamExplorer`.

Comment: Yes that is what the View menu says it is :) and that is what works.  You have to do both in that order.